# Proving Continuity in Multiple Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

**The Exercise:**

$f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)$ if $x \ne 0$

$f(x,y)=0$ otherwise

Where is $f$ continuous?

**My Attempt:**

At $(0,0)$, let y=kx. $lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y) = lim_{x\to 0}f(x,kx)=k/(1+k^2)$ which does not necessarily equal $f(0,0)=0$, so it is not continuous at (0,0).

At $(0,b)$, $b\ne 0$, I suspect that it is not continuous, so I tried letting $x=b-y$. This relationship produced no inconsistency with the definition of continuity, since $lim_{y\to b}f(y-b,y)=0=f(0,b)$. I'm having trouble thinking of other relationships between x and y which might produce a contradiction similar to what I have for $(0,0)$. I also tried proving that it IS continuous, which I have had serious trouble doing. I want that, for all $\epsilon$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. if $\|(x,y)-(0,b)\|<\delta$, then $|f(x,y)-f(0,b)|<\epsilon$. I don't know where to go from here.

At $(a,b)$, $a\ne 0$, I am having the same issue as proving continuity at $(0,b)$. I would expect it to be continuous but I don't know how to use the definition to prove that this is the case.

Comment: I think this function is continuous everywhere but at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Away from $(0,0)$ you can compute the limit of the ratio as a ratio of limits because the denominator limit is not $0$ there. So the function is continuous everywhere else.

Comment: Oh, so does saying $lim_{(x,y)\to (a,b)}f(x,y)=f(a,b)$ where $f=(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)$, basically use the same principle as saying that $lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=f(1)$, where f(x)=x?

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are polynomials (as in this case) and $\lim q \neq 0$ (as in this case), then $\lim \frac{p}{q}= \frac{\lim p}{\lim q}$ (I'm abbreviating the limit notation here). Both limits can be evaluated by plugging in since polynomials are continuous everywhere. So...yes.